# How to reconstruct an image from tensor of flattened patches in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a PyTorch tensor which is of the shape (196,256). This corresponds to a 224x224 image made from 196 patches where the top left patch is made from the first row of the original tensor- a 16x16 patch. The patch immediately right of this is made from the second row of the original tensor...and so on. How do I rearrange this tensor into the original image of 224x224?

I tried patches.view(224,224), but it mixes the rows and so does not correspond to the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Tensor.as_strided`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.as_strided.html#torch.Tensor.as_strided). For example, if we have a 6x6 tensor `img` that originally looks like

```py
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

but represented as 9 patches of shape 2x2 each, arranged in a tensor `patches` like

```py
tensor([[ 0,  1,  6,  7],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  9],
        [ 4,  5, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 18, 19],
        [14, 15, 20, 21],
        [16, 17, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 30, 31],
        [26, 27, 32, 33],
        [28, 29, 34, 35]])
```

we can use

```py
patches.as_strided((3, 2, 3, 2), (3 * 2 * 2, 2, 2 * 2, 1)).reshape_as(img)
```

to get `img` back. In your case, the correct code should be

```py
patches.as_strided((14, 16, 14, 16), (14 * 16 * 16, 16, 16 * 16, 1)).reshape_as(img)
```